# How to run IIS under different user

Tags: iis, w3wp

I am using IIS 7.5 under Windows 7 and I'm trying to run World Wide Web Publishing Service process under a different user than the local system account. I have been able to change the account I want to use, but this brought up an error when trying to start the proccess:

> Error 1079: The account specified for this service is different from
>   the account specified for other services running in the same process.

I can't seem to find anywhere which process should also be modified.

Please note, I don't want only the app pool to be impersonating a user, I want the whole service to do so.

Comment: Ok...to start with which version of Windows/IIS? And why do you want to do this?

Comment: @Kev IIS 7.5. I want to be able start proccesses for the logged in user that will launch an interface in the ui thread. So basicly, launching applications that will have some user interface that will be visible on the "server", which in this case is my own machine.

Comment: You'll never be able to launch applications and have them interact with the desktop in IIS7. I answered a similar question yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/a/19828290/419